# Forming a box around elements after hovering over li to display hidden ul

Tags: javascript, html, border

I have a ul within an li. When I hover over my li, the ul appears. I'm trying to make it so when that happens, both the li and ul have borders that form a box.

I've set up a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Jfpz/

What I want to do is:

- Make it so the border around my li remains. Maybe I should use active instead of hover on my li? Or use JavaScript/jQuery?
- Make it so the border around my ul stops under the li, so there are no borders inside of the box. So instead of it looking like there is a separate border around the ul and one around the li, it would be one continuous line along the outside. (EX: If you look at Stack Overflow, the "active" "oldest" "votes" links look like they don't have a bottom-border. The long line doesn't continue under those links.) Is there an easy way to style that? Do I make a bottom-border for the li that is extra thick and white? Or is there another way to hide the border-top of the ul that comes under the li?

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/2Jfpz/1/

Comment: Cool, how'd you get the li border to stick? The only thing I'm having trouble with is the top border of the ul. I'll edit my post to explain further.

Comment: I changed it from `a.linkBorder:hover` to `#linkli:hover`. Notice I added this id to the first `li` element.